# Rails how to download only current record when clicked download button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm new to rails. Im developing an app which contains adding customers.In that I have download button.When I click download button It should download the current customer page in csv file.

**Controller**

```
def create
  @customer_detail = CustomerDetail.new(customer_detail_params)
  @customer_detail.company_profile_id = current_user.company_profile.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @customer_detail.save
       format.html { redirect_to edit_customer_detail_path(@customer_detail), notice: 'customerDetails was successfully created.' }
      # format.html { render 'edit', notice: 'customerDetails was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end

def index
  @customer_details = CustomerDetail.all
end

def destroy
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render text: @customer_details.to_csv }
    if @customer_detail.update(customer_detail_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @customer_detail, notice: 'customer_details was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
.fieldset
  .row
    .col-sm-3
      = f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary"
    .col-sm-3
      = f.submit "cancel", type: :reset, class: "btn btn-primary"
    .col-sm-3
      = link_to "Download", edit_customer_detail(format: "csv"), class: "btn btn-primary"
    .col-sm-3
      = link_to("Print", "javascript:print()", class: "btn btn-primary")
```

The problem is it downloads all the records from of the form. I dont know whether to action is to be given in update or edit.If i give the path edit_customer_detail instead of customer_details_(path) it shows template error and no route matches error when clicking download button.can someone please help me.I've attached the output link here. thanks in advance!!

[Customer_details.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gpsy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**model**

```html
def to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << self.class.column_names
      csv << self.attributes.values_at(*self.class.column_names)
      end
    end
```

**controller**

```html
def download_csv
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @customer_detail.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

**view**

```html
.col-sm-3
              - if @customer_detail.save
                = link_to "Download", download_csv_customer_detail_path(@customer_detail.id, format: "csv"), class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I've added seperate method of action in controller and changed method and routes.finally got an answer

Answer (score 0):

In controller's update method, change below line:

```
format.csv { render text: @customer_details.to_csv } with
format.csv { render text: @customer_detail.to_csv }
```

Comment: changed!.It shows me template is missing error if I give customer_details_path. And no route matches if I give edit_customer_detail. can u help me further?

Comment: = link_to "Download", customer_details_path(format: "csv"), class: "btn btn-primary"

Comment: where I have to replace in my code?.in form? or controller?. can u explain little detaily

Comment: In your view file, where you have download button

Comment: Im getting template is missing error.if replacing customer_details_path. earlier it has downloaded all the records.now it leads to template is missing error

Comment: In your view, on link_to download, call a new method by passing customerID and write csv downlaod code there. Define approproate route in routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

In application.rb 
add `require 'csv'`

Change your update function to

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render text: @customer_detail.to_csv }
    if @customer_detail.update(customer_detail_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @customer_detail, notice: 'customer_details was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
```

You were downloading report for all users because `@customer_details = CustomerDetail.all` returns data for all users.

Comment: I've already added require 'csv'. so It downloads but not current user form.It downloads all the user records.It shows me template is missing error if I give customer_details_path. And no route matches if I give edit_customer_detail. Thank you!. can u help me further?

Comment: @HariPrakash You don't have a matching route for edit_customer: /customers/:id/edit(.:format) customers#edit. Can u create a function and route to edit customer details